# Download newly created word file straight away instead of saving to disk

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I'm creating a word file using interop and it works fine. At the moment I'm passing in a filepath to create the new file from after find and replacing any vars inside. 
Ideally i'd like it to once its created the file automatically serve/download the file through the browser and not leave anything on the server hdd. Is this possible? Here's my code i'm using to create the file;

```
  public static void CreateWordDoc(List<objReplace> lstReplace, String TemplateFile, String OutputPath)
    {
        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var doc = app.Documents.Open(TemplateFile);

        var range = doc.Range();
        foreach (var ro in lstReplace)
        {
            range.Find.Execute(FindText: ro.Find, Replace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: ro.Replace);

            var shapes = doc.Shapes;

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in shapes)
            {
                var initialText = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                var resultingText = initialText.Replace(ro.Find, ro.Replace);
                shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = resultingText;
            }
        }
        doc.SaveAs2(OutputPath);

        doc.Close();

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are automating Word on the server (ASP.NET?).

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

You may consider using the Open XML SDK for dealing with Open XML documents, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. Or just use any third-party components designed for the server side execution.